# react antd input defaultValue is not displayed

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using the Input component of react,antd.
If you enter more than 10 characters, an error will be displayed.
When the value of value is null, the value of value is set to 3. I checked the value in console.log() and the default value is 3.
The defaultValue is not applied.
Somebody help me, please...

[code](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-tree-xe4xm?file=/src/App.js:0-1146)

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Input, Form } from "antd";

const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(null);
  const [onSave, setOnSave] = React.useState(null);
  const handleInputChange = React.useCallback((e) => {
    setValue(Number(e.target.value));
  }, []);

  const onSaveBlur = React.useCallback(() => {
    if (String(value).length < 10) {
      setOnSave(true);
    } else {
      setOnSave(false);
    }
  }, [value]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (value === null) {
      setValue(3);
    }
  }, [value]);
  console.log(value);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <Form>
        <Form.Item
          name="input"
          rules={[
            { max: 10, message: "length should be less then 10 letters!" }
          ]}
        >
          <Input
            type="number"
            value={value}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            onBlur={onSaveBlur}
          ></Input>
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Only value prop will work not need to add defaultValue prop

Comment: You are mixing controlled components vs uncontrolled components, you should first define if you want the component to be uncontrolled and follow the guidelines on how to do it, or stick to controlled and use value instead of defaultValue.

Comment: You need to leave it controlled and use the value instead of defaultValue. What kind of code should I write to do this?I do not understand the meaning of the above.

Comment: Somebody help me, please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can understand that you want to show an error message when number length becomes more than 10. This is what you've correctly applied here [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMKja.png)
But as you're using input field inside of a form, there is a different approach to work with default value and onChange Event. DefaultValue and onChange event will not give you the expected output when you use them inside of form element. Here you must you form methods like this

```
'https://pastebin.com/raw/1NmR4tQT'
```

study more about ant Design Form methods from here [Learn More about ant design form methods](https://ant.design/components/form/#header)